# The difference that quotation marks make in find command

Tags: command-line, find

When I have a nested directory `find . -name "*.py" -print` command gives me all the python scripts beneath current directory. However, `find . -name *.py -print` returns only the python scrips in current directory.

Is this expected behavior? What makes this difference? I use Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably not the same command. You could put `echo` in front to check.

```
$ echo find . -name "*.py" -print
find . -name *.py -print

$ echo find . -name *.py -print
find . -name foobar.py barfoo.py -print
```

Without quotes, the shell expanded `*.py`, so `find` gets different arguments, which yields different results.

You should always quote `*` when you want a command to see `*` literally. Otherwise the behaviour will be erratic (the command works as long as there are no `*.py` files for the shell to expand to).

Answer (score 2):

Because the shell expands the wildcard when you don't protect the pattern.

You always have to use some quotes.