# recursively find *.c files for dos2unix processing

Tags: find

The goal is to `find` [*.c files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nbish0be1pvmha/raymond-floppydisk.zip?dl=0) to be processed with `dos2unix`:

```
find . -name *.c | xargs dos2unix -f
```

In an attempt to troubleshoot the above command:

```
user@host:~/csim/exercise$ find . -name *.c
./6-1/dinph_3p.c
./6-1/dinph_pi.c
./9-2/lift.c
./6-4/cmptr.c
./8-7/station.c
./7-4/hire.c
./5-2/ran_test.c
./8-4/cmptrm.c
./9-5/trunked.c
./8-5/computer.c
./9-3/aloha.c
./12-3/mcpu.c
./10-5/abp_pi.c
./6-2/dinph_3p.c
./6-2/dinph_pi.c
```

Why is that when BASH is moved up one directory:

```
$ cd ..
```

The same command does not return at least the .c files listed above?

```
user@host:~/csim$ find . -name *.c
find: paths must precede expression: random.c
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]
```

Comment: See [The difference that quotation marks make in find command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86621/the-difference-that-quotation-marks-make-in-find-command) and links therein

Answer (score 5):

When you're searching for a wildcard (e.g., `*.c`), then you really ought to include it in single quotes.  When you moved up one directory, my guess is that you entered a directory with at least two files ending in `.c`, one of which was `random.c`.  In that case, bash expanded `*.c` to the matching files.

Assume that the directory contained `hi.c` and `random.c`, then

```
find . -name *.c
```

Becomes:

```
find . -name hi.c random.c
```

Including `*.c` in single quotes will cause the shell to not expand it.

To find each `.c` file under `~/csim` and process with `dos2unix`:

`find ~/csim -type f -name '*.c' | xargs dos2unix -f`

Comment: Or `find ~/csim -type f -name '*.c' -exec dos2unix -f {} +` to avoid the pipe.

Comment: @Kusalananda  What is the motivation to avoid the pipe?

Comment: @gatorback Twofold in this particular case: 1) Supports all filenames, even those with embedded newlines (could also be fixed by using `find -print0` and `xargs -0`, if supported) and 2) Neater (i.e. my personal preference). Oh, and some `xargs` implementation would run the utility (`dos2unix -f` here) regardless of whether it gets any input or not, possibly causing an error when `find` doesn't find anything.

Comment: @Kusalananda, it's not limited to newline here. It's newline, spc, tab (possibly other whitespace depending on locale and xargs implementation), single quote, double quote, backslash (and possibly sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the locale, and possibly paths longer than 255 bytes with some `xargs` implementations). Without `-print0`/`-0`, the output of `find` is not compatible with the expected input format of `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some more explanation to that of @Andy's.

Basically `find` command needs a file name or a pattern, as a argument(place holder) to the `-name` option.

when you try to run `echo *.c`, in the directory that contains one or more `.c` files, the result would be space-separated names of those files like

```
$echo *.c
abc.c bcd.c
```

If there are no `.c` files in the directory then the result must be

```
$echo *.c
*.c
```

Likewise `find . -name *.c` in the directory that has more than 1 `.c` file, `*.c` in `find` gets replaced by names all `.c` files present in that directory(*.c is expaned as multiple arguments of the option `-name`). That must be something like this, `find . -name abc.c bcd.c`. Here the error you get occurs when find starts searching `bcd.c` after successful search of  `abc.c` because `-name` take only one argument.(if there is only 1 `.c` then it gets written as result, no more search in the sub-directories takes place)

But, when there are no `.c` files in the directory actual meaning of `*` in `*.c` gets retained.

So, when you were in `~/csim/exercise` and tried to use `find` to search all `*.c`, I think there were no `*.c` files in the directory where `find` command had run. that is why wildcard meaning of `*` in `*.c` is retained and search in the sub-directories becomes successful. After `cd ..`, search was unsuccessful because I suspect `~/csim/` has more than 1 `*.c` files.

Solution is much simpler, escaping wildcard would be sufficient. Use any one of this.

```
find .  -name '*.c'
or
find .  -name \*.c
or
find .  -name "*.c"
```